# Asp.Net core 2 Round trip external login additional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

Currently, I generate an invitation key that gets embedded into the login URL and sent to users:

eg: https://localhost:44338/account/login/mykey

I also enabled google authentication

[image]

How do round trip "mykey" when the user clicks on the google link to have it available when the user gets created in ExternalLoginConfirmation (in the default asp.net core setup).

EDIT: For example what code should I add to this method

```
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string key, string returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
    var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);


    return Challenge(properties, provider);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually more of an OAuth question than something specific to ASP.NET. It is done by encoding a complex object and passing it to the OAuth provider in the `state` query paremeter.

Take for example this JSON object:

```
{
    "validation": "aGUID",
    "key": "invitationKey"
}
```

If you Url Encode this value, you can pass it as the `state`:

```
...&state=%7B%22validation%22%3A+%22aGUID%22%2C%22key%22%3A+%22invitationKey%22%7D+
```

When you receieve the response from the provider, you decode the `state` value and deserialize it back into an object. You can then validate the GUID in `validation` matches what you sent and process the invitation key from the `key` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do you pass the state in Asp.net Core 2

Answer (score 0):

Marc LaFleur's answer is correct, but as your follow-up question notes, you're trying to figure out how to do this with ASP.NET Core. The solution is to wire up some of the [`OpenIdConnectEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-2.0) which allows you to intercept various parts of the OIDC flow. This goes in your setup method where you register for OIDC:

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = appconfig["OidcAuthority"];
    options.ClientId = appconfig["OidcClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = appconfig["OidcClientSecret"];
    // other config omitted

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.Properties.Items.Add("invitationkey", "somevalue");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        },

        OnTicketReceived = context =>
        {
            var invitation = context.Properties.Items["invitationkey"];
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
};
```

There are quite a few events available. One of my sytems allows our users to auth via Google, but we use it through IdentityServer4, so offhand I don't know the specific response event. You'll have to review them to figure out which is appropriate for the type of flow you're using and how your identity provider responds, but this should get you on the right track.

Since the return-trip event is defined in startup, you'll have to come up with a way to "share" that value to other parts of your application (inject some type of simple caching service, for example).